# Python - How to add space on each 3 characters?

Tags: python

I need to add a space on each 3 characters of a python string but don't have many clues on how to do it.

The string:

```
345674655
```

The output that I need:

```
345 674 655
```

Any clues on how to achieve this?

Best Regards,

Comment: What's the desired output for `1234`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You just need a way to iterate over your string in chunks of 3.

```
>>> a = '345674655'
>>> [a[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]
['345', '674', '655']
```

Then `' '.join` the result.

```
>>> ' '.join([a[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)])
'345 674 655'
```

Note that:

```
>>> [''.join(x) for x in zip(*[iter(a)]*3)]
['345', '674', '655']
```

also works for partitioning the string.  This will work for arbitrary iterables (not just strings), but truncates the string where the length isn't divisible by 3.  To recover the behavior of the original, you can use `itertools.izip_longest` (`itertools.zip_longest` in py3k):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [''.join(x) for x in itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(a)]*3, fillvalue=' ')]
['345', '674', '655']
```

Of course, you pay a little in terms of easy reading for the improved generalization in these latter answers ...

Comment: What if The length is not divisible by 3

Can we do something like this
- start from left, after every 3rd digit insert the space

Answer (score 4):

Best Function based on [@mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson)'s answer

```
def litering_by_three(a):
    return " ".join([a[::-1][i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)])[::-1]
#  replace (↑) with you character like ","
```

output example:

```
>>> x="500000"
>>> print(litering_by_three(x))
'500 000'
>>>
```

or for `,` example:

```
>>> def litering_by_three(a):
>>>         return " ".join([a[::-1][i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)])[::-1]
>>>     #  replace (↑) with you character like ","
>>> print(litering_by_three(x))
'500,000'
>>>
```

Comment: For 2000 this produces 200 0 and not 2 000

Comment: Thanks @nyx69 i just fixed it

Answer (score 2):

a one-line solution will be

```
" ".join(splitAt(x,3))
```

however, Python is missing a `splitAt()` function, so define yourself one

```
def splitAt(w,n):
    for i in range(0,len(w),n):
        yield w[i:i+n]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about reversing the string to jump by 3 starting from the units, then reversing again. The goal is to obtain "12 345".

```
n="12345"    
" ".join([n[::-1][i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(n), 3)])[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Join with '-' the concatenated of the first, second and third characters of each 3 characters:

```
' '.join(a+b+c for a,b,c in zip(x[::3], x[1::3], x[2::3]))
```

Be sure string length is dividable by 3