# Appending elements in front of a desired number in a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to slice a list of numbers in a specific way. I want my program to insert a space everytime it comes across 0. f.e. Input is `"01365400606"` and my output should be

`[0, 1, 3, 6, " ", 5, 4, 0, 0, " ", 6, 0, 6]`

but my output is `[0, 1, 3, ' ', 5, 4, 0, ' ', 6, 0, 6]`.

The problem is that my function is replacing the numbers and putting `" "` to that place. I want it to put it in front of desired number and not removing any elements from the list.

Here is the code:

```py
number0 = "01365400606"

def NumberCutter(number):
    numberList = []
    numberListSolution = []
    count = 0

    for e in number:
        e = int(e)
        numberList.append(e)       

    for e in numberList:
        count += 1
        if count % 4 == 0:
            numberListSolution.append(" ")
        else:
            numberListSolution.append(e)

    return numberListSolution

print(NumberCutter(number0))
```

Comment: Are you looking for `number0.replace('00', '00 ')`?

Comment: Your description of inserting a space every time a 0 is encountered doesn't match the output of ` [0, 1, 3, 6, " ", 5, 4, 0, 0, " ", 6, 0, 6]`...

Comment: Hmmm, yes I am sorry. Later I am planning to convert this list to a string, so " " will be a space. I am trying to add " " after every 4 elements...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15254195/1324033

Comment: from your code, it looks like it inserts into every fourth space, regardless of what number is there.

Comment: Hmm, this link definetly helps, but I am better with working with lists than strings, that is why I am doing it with list and then converting the result to string...

Comment: this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. You want to group 4 digits together and have spaces in between, you think that you need to create a list with those spaces and use a join, so you ask a question about that. Instead, just "group" 4 digits, don't create this list with spaces. Use a join once you've grouped 4 digits, passing space as the join parameter.

Comment: @RaZiiiGG I updated my answer, with a working shorter version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying this:

```py
number0 = "01365400606"

def NumberCutter(number):
    numberList = []
    numberListSolution = []
    count = 0

    for e in number:
        e = int(e)
        numberList.append(e)       

    for e in numberList:
        count += 1
        numberListSolution.append(e) # Always adding the number
        if count % 4 == 0:
            numberListSolution.append(" ") # Add space if needed after the number
    return numberListSolution

print(NumberCutter(number0))
```

## Update

I think this solution is looks better and pretty readable:

```py
def NumberCutter(number):
     integers = [int(i) for i in number] # Convert the str to list of integers
     spaces = len(integers) # Count how many spaces should be in the list
     for i in range(1,spaces+1):
         integers.insert(((i)*4) + (i-1), ' ') # Insert space in the right place
     return integers
```

Explation:
The indexes of the spaces need to be 4, 9, 14, 19

so the value of `(i*4) + (i + 1)` allow as to get this sequels of numbers

Comment: You don’t need numberList as number is already iterable. You may need numberListSolution.append(int(e))